# Correlation of similar variables in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have slightly edited the data table.

I would like to correlate variable with similar name in my dataset:

```
   A_y  B_y  C_y  A_p  B_p  C_p
1  15   52   32   30   98   56
2  30   99   60   56   46   25
3  10   25   31   20   22   30
     ..........
n  55   23   85   12   34   52
```

I would like to obtain correlation of

1. A_y-A_p: 0.78
2. B_y-B_p: 0.88
3. C_y-C_p: 0.93

How can I do it in R? Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't think that you can have two variables with the same name in a single dataset.

Comment: In what way are the variable names similar? In your example, the names turn up twice, which is not possible in a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really dangerous. Behavior of data.frames with invalid column names is undefined by the language definition. Duplicated column names are invalid.

You should restructure your input data. Anyway, here is an approach with your input data.

```
DF <- read.table(text = "   A  B  C  A  B  C
1 15 52 32 30 98 56
2 30 99 60 56 46 25
3 10 25 31 20 22 30", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

sapply(unique(names(DF)), function(s) do.call(cor, unname(DF[, names(DF) == s])))
#        A          B          C 
#0.9995544  0.1585501 -0.6004010

#compare:
cor(c(15, 30, 10), c(30, 56, 20))
#[1] 0.9995544
```

Comment: I have slightly edited the data table. Dear @ThomasIsCoding, Thank you very much for suggestions. The calculation I want to do is. I have a dateset with monthly precipitation (5 months during vegetation period) and crop yield for 200 farmers over the 15 years. I would like to check correlation between each farm yield with each month precipitation.

Comment: Can we assume the sorting? Then `mapply(cor, DF[, seq_len(ncol(DF)/2)], DF[, seq_len(ncol(DF)/2) + ncol(DF)/2])`.

Comment: when I copy and paste and run above given code I receive such ERROR: Error in do.call(cor, unname(DF[, names(DF) == s])) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string

Comment: Then you must have defined a `cor` variable in your code. `cor` is a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option

```
within(
  rev(
    stack(
      Map(
        function(x) do.call(cor, unname(x)),
        split.default(df, unique(gsub("_.*", "", names(df))))
      )
    )
  ),
  ind <- sapply(
    ind,
    function(x) {
      paste0(grep(paste0("^", x), names(df), value = TRUE),
        collapse = "-"
      )
    }
  )
)
```

which gives

```
      ind     values
1 A_y-A_p  0.9995544
2 B_y-B_p  0.1585501
3 C_y-C_p -0.6004010
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A_y = c(15L, 30L, 10L), B_y = c(52L, 99L, 25L), 
    C_y = c(32L, 60L, 31L), A_p = c(30L, 56L, 20L), B_p = c(98L, 
    46L, 22L), C_p = c(56L, 25L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: I have slightly edited the data table. Dear @Roland, Thank you very much for suggestions. The calculation I want to do is. I have a dateset with monthly precipitation (5 months during vegetation period) and crop yield for 200 farmers over the 15 years. I would like to check correlation between each farm yield with each month precipitation.

Comment: thanks. When I run this code I receive such ERROR:  Error in do.call(cor, unname(x)) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string.